# I want to navigate to a div using a button HTML

Tags: php, html, navigation

I am using this code for button:

```
 <input type="button"
        style="margin-left:350px"
        id="replybottom"
        name="replybottom"
        onClick="#navigateHere"
        class="button"
        value="Reply"></div>
```

this is my div:

```
<div id="navigateHere"
     name="navigateHere"
     class="convomsg12">
```

Comment: Great, what have you tried?

Comment: This is something you could easily answer yourself by putting in the tiny bit extra effort of googling.

Comment: javascript not working its just turning the button red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick="#navigateHere" This is Wrong way to Navigate.

Instead of that use this code.

```
   function goto(url)
    {
    window.location=url;

    }
```

Here your Button

```
<div onclick="goto('#navigateHere')">Replay</div>
```

If you want to give button you can give like this

```
<input type="button"  onclick="goto('#navigateHere')"  value="Replay"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using an anchor instead of a button

```
<a href='#navigateHere'>Reply</a>
```

Or you can add a javascript event on your button, like this:

```
<button onClick='window.location="#navigateHere"'>Reply</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

An `onclick` attribute should contain JavaScript, not a URL.

However, since you are linking somewhere: use a link. You can apply CSS to make it look however you want.

```
<a href="#navigateHere">Reply</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Farla's response should work, perhaps check if you have other event handlers attached to the event.
With this

```
<input type="button" style="height:400px" onclick="window.location='#zzzz'; event.stopImmediatePropagation()"/>

<div id="zzzz" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

you can stop other handlers that are attached to the same event. If you had (for example)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("button").click(function () { alert("click response"); })
    });
</script>
```

it would not be triggered.
Just beware it may interfere with functionality you may have (plugins or own code) that may depend on those extra handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Late but might work better than other answers.

```js
const goTo = () => {
   document.getElementById("hero").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
   document.activeElement.blur(); //optional if you want to blur active element.
}
```

```
<button onClick="goTo()">Go To</button>
```